# How to run a sub when an item within a listbox is double clicked

Tags: vb.net

I have a listbox which gradually gets populated with orders as the program is used. However, I want to open a separate form when any item within the listbox is double clicked.

```
handles lstbox.selectedindexchanged
```

Isn't what I'm looking for and neither is:

```
handles lstbox.doubleclick
```

As they just run whenever any index is clicked once or anywhere on the control is double clicked, respectively.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing built-in on the WinForms ListBox control, so use the MouseDoubleClick event to simulate it:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_MouseDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles ListBox1.MouseDoubleClick
  Dim index As Integer = ListBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.Location)
  If index > -1 AndAlso index = ListBox1.SelectedIndex Then
    MessageBox.Show(ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString)
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks :) this would be a rather useful thing for them to add in in .net 6

Comment: @JamesHughes Aint gonna happen.  WinForms is in, a-hem, "stable mode".

Comment: One can hope... Microsoft might yet learn that there is nothing that cannot be improved

Comment: Just tried to implement your solution and it is throwing this error when I try and compile it...
`BC36663 Option Strict On does not allow narrowing in implicit type conversions between method 'Private Sub lstbxJobs_doubleClickItem(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)' and delegate 'Delegate Sub EventHandler(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)'` Any ideas?

Comment: @JamesHughes Using the wrong handler?  My code handles the MouseDoubleClick event, not the DoubleClick event.